# Complex Analysis Dense Set Problem

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

The Problem: Suppose $f(z) = e^{i\theta}z$.  Show that if $\theta$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, then the orbit of $ z \in \mathbb{C}$ is dense in the circle with radius $|z|$ and at the center of the origin.

My Attempt: Now I think that I am supposed to show that the orbit of z is dense inside the circle with radius z. Let $\delta > 0$ I can define another point $z_{0} \in \mathbb{C}$ which $0<|z_{0}|< |z|$. Then for any integer k, $|f^{k} (z_{0}) -f(z)| < \delta$. The problem I am having is choosing a $\delta$ so that the orbit of $z_{0}$ is contained inside the circle with radius z.

I am not also sure if I am on the right track.

Could you just give me some hints or feedback on what I need to do?

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're thinking about this problem correctly.  Note that $\left|f(z)\right| = \left|z\right|$, so that repeated applications of $f$ stay on the circle, not "in" ( meaning inside ) the circle.  Also, I don't think the inequality you gave is correct.

Your function $f$ is just rotation by $\theta$ degrees.  So, one way to think of the problem is rephrasing as: starting from the point $(1,0)$, can you successively rotate by $\theta$ to get a point on the circle with angle less than $\epsilon > 0$?

EDIT:

You need to start with a point $w$ on the circle, i.e. $|w| = |z|$ and then show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $k$ such that $|f^k(z) - w| < \epsilon$.   This problem can be pretty easily reduced to showing that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $k$ such that the angle between $f^k(z)$ and $w$ is less than $\epsilon$.  So, let $\xi = Arg(z)$, so that $Arg(f^k(z)) = \xi + k\cdot \theta \pmod {2\pi}$, and let $\zeta = Arg(w)$.  So, this reduces to showing that if $\theta$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, then there is a $k$ such that $\zeta - \xi - k\cdot \theta \pmod{2\pi}$ is less than $\epsilon$.  I guess I'm being a little hand-wavy on that since there's no order on elements of $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{R}$, but I think it's clear what I mean.  Dividing everything by $2\pi$, this boils down to showing that given a real number $a$ between $0$ and $1$ and an irrational number $c$, there exists a natural number $k$ such that $a-k\cdot c \pmod 1$ is less than $\epsilon$.

Does this help?

Comment: Okay that makes more sense because the problem did not explain clearly what it meant to be "in" the circle. Now I know that this is just a rotation mapping. I just want to make sure if I understand this correctly. So I can take a point, $z_{0}$, and just find an orbit for $|z_{0}|$ which the angle between z and the orbit from  $z_{0}$ is less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: Technically what you need to show is that for any point on the circle there is some iterate such that the angle between the iterate and that point on the circle is within $\epsilon$ of that point.

Comment: Okay. So if that is the case, then for any complex number z, which is the angle is not a rational multiple of $\pi$. So, I can define a $z_{0}$ which the angle is just a rational approximation of the angle represented in z. Then, I can define a $\epsilon$ which is an open arc on the circle, $(z-\epsilon, z+\epsilon)$, and define $\epsilon= {|z|}{\theta}$ which is the arc formula for a circle.

Comment: Okay. If that is the case, then I can define a set $J = (z-\epsilon, z+\epsilon)$ which $\epsilon = |z| * \frac{\theta}{n} $ . That is just the arc formula for the circle. Then just for any complex point, z, I can choose a point $z_{0}$ which the angle is just a rational number approximation of the angle for z.  We also know that the angle for z is not a rational multiple of pi. Am I getting the right idea?

Comment: Sorry, there's a formatting issue with one of your comments, and it's obscuring the other one for me as well.  From what I can read, there are some errors in what you're saying ( for example, there's no such thing as an interval $(z-\epsilon, z+\epsilon)$, but I'm thinking you have discerned the essence of the argument, and just need to explain it better.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. In one of my textbook I have found, they have defined a dense set as follows: Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ Then a set, $A$ is dense in $I$ if for any $z \in I$, any open interval containing x, must intersect A. In other words, for each $\delta > 0$, the open interval $J= (x-\delta, x+ \delta)$ contains a point in $A$. So I am kind of trying to prove the function , $f(z)$ is dense under the circle with radius $z$ in this fashion. I defined a $\delta$, which is represented as $\epsilon$ in this problem,  and defined a set J as the open arc on the circle with center z.

Comment: What I am trying to do is I am defining an $\epsilon$ which $\epsilon$ is just $\frac{\theta}{2^{n}}$ which theta is just the angle generated by the complex number $z$. Then I just take a point $z_{0}$ which the angle generated by $z_{0}$ is just a rational approximation of the angle generated by $z$. Since we know that z is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, we could just generate a complex number, $z_{0}$ which the angle of $z_{0}$ is just a rational approximation of z by n decimal places. That was my way of explaining it I guess.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing defintions.  I see $x$ and $z$.  There's no such thing as an open interval in the complex numbers the way you're writing it, because there's no notion of "between" two complex numbers.

Comment: This website is acting weird on my computer. This is my first time using this website and I apologize for the disorganization. I really thank you for your help, patience, and understanding. Anyway, if I cannot construct the set J in this fashion, how I am supposed to define a set J, with respect to the circle and the Complex Numbers?